# mysqldump on windows ignoring user/password

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Using mysqldump on windows(2003-server - MariaDB) produces following error:

```
mysqldump: Got error: 1045: "Access denied for user 'ODBC'@'localhost' (using password: YES)" when trying to connect
```

Commands I used:

```
mysqldump --user=root --password=password -h127.0.0.1 --port=3306 database > backup.sql
mysqldump -uroot -ppassword database > backup.sql
mysqldump -uroot -p(enter password on promt) database > backup.sql
mysqldump -u root -p password database > backup.sql
mysqldump -u root -ppassword database > backup.sql
```

Etc, anything I used, same error popped up.
Looks like some default-hardcoded user/password is used.
I can connect to mysql -uroot -p just fine.

Internets have seen this error before, but I have not seen proper solution to this or I am oblivios to something.

Any insight would be amazing.
Thanks.

Comment: May be you don't have permissions to [database]

Comment: See how to store your password in a config file so that you're not prompted every time: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9293090/470749

Answer (score 1):

Double check your `-` char in your commands. Sometimes copy&paste produces a different hyphen char.

Your command below should work:

```
mysqldump -u root -ppassword database > backup.sql
```