# Shell script for recursive sqlmetadata backup

Tags: bash, shell

I am writing a shell script to automate the sql metadata backup everyday. I am stuck in between. My approach is to backup sql metadata everyday and delete the old backups keeping last 3 backup for safety. Please help me out with the command to delete the previous backups keeping the last 3 backups.

```
FILE= mysql_metadata_backup_$( date '+%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S' ).sql
mysqldump -u userID --all-databases > ${FILE}
```

Comment: You could use `ls  -t` for that.

Comment: It sorts the output, and the newest files are listed first.. See my answer. I have explained things inside the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you could use bash parameter expansion to achieve your objective.

Place the below bash script in the folder containing your backups.

```
#!/bin/bash
file_list=($( ls -t mysql_metadata_backup*))
# The '-t' parameter of the 'ls' sorts the output according to modification time with newest displayed first.
rm $( echo ${file_list[@]:3})
# The ':3' does the magic slicing the array from the index 3
# All the files except the newest three are passed to the "rm" command.
```

Running it will delete all the backups except the newest three.

Perhaps you could consider adding a **cron** job to automate this.

**Reference:**

[Bash Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)

Comment: I placed the file in the same folder and ran the script. its giving error. 
    ls: cannot access mysql_metadata_backup_Sat: No such file or directory

Comment: `FILE= mysql_metadata_backup_$( date '+%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S' ).sql` is incorrect i guess. You could do `temp=$( date '+%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S') && FILE=mysql_backup_$temp.sql`

Comment: Awesome Sjsam, It worked with your last answer. Thanks a lot

Comment: Sjsam the code works fine but I dont want to enter my password in the script file. Can you suggest me on that.

Comment: @Naveen : Regarding the password, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9293042/mysqldump-without-the-password-prompt)