# backup up db using php script and cron job

Tags: php, mysql, sql, backup-strategies

I'm using the script I posted below and it appeared to have worked based on the email and the fact it actually generated the file. However, It didn't backup anything.

**Here is the output stored in the file it created:**

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;

SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";

SET AUTOCOMMIT=0;

START TRANSACTION;

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;

COMMIT;
```

**Here is the php script being used to generate the backup:**

```
    #!/usr/bin/php
<?php

backup_tables();

// backup all tables in db
function backup_tables()
{
    $day_of_backup = ''; //possible values: `Monday` `Tuesday` `Wednesday` `Thursday` `Friday` `Saturday` `Sunday`
    $backup_path = '/home/user/public_html/path/to/BACKUP.file/destination/'; //make sure it ends with "/"
    $db_host = 'localhost';
    $db_user = 'root';
    $db_pass = 'replace_w_ur_password';
    $db_name = 'replace_w_ur_db_name';

    //set the correct date for filename
    if (date('l') == $day_of_backup) {
        $date = date("Y-m-d");
    } else {
        //set $date to the date when last backup had to occur
        $datetime1 = date_create($day_of_backup);
        $date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($day_of_backup.'-1 days'));
    }

    if (!file_exists($backup_path.$date.'-backup'.'.sql')) {

        //connect to db
        $link = mysqli_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass);
        mysqli_set_charset($link,'utf8');
        mysqli_select_db($link,$db_name);

        //get all of the tables
        $tables = array();
        $result = mysqli_query($link, 'SHOW TABLES');
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result))
        {
            $tables[] = $row[0];
        }

        //disable foreign keys (to avoid errors)
        $return = 'SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;' . "\r\n";
        $return.= 'SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";' . "\r\n";
        $return.= 'SET AUTOCOMMIT=0;' . "\r\n";
        $return.= 'START TRANSACTION;' . "\r\n";

        //cycle through
        foreach($tables as $table)
        {
            $result = mysqli_query($link, 'SELECT * FROM '.$table);
            $num_fields = mysqli_num_fields($result);
            $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
            $i_row = 0;

            //$return.= 'DROP TABLE '.$table.';'; 
            $row2 = mysqli_fetch_row(mysqli_query($link,'SHOW CREATE TABLE '.$table));
            $return.= "\n\n".$row2[1].";\n\n"; 

            if ($num_rows !== 0) {
                $row3 = mysqli_fetch_fields($result);
                $return.= 'INSERT INTO '.$table.'( ';
                foreach ($row3 as $th) 
                { 
                    $return.= '`'.$th->name.'`, '; 
                }
                $return = substr($return, 0, -2);
                $return.= ' ) VALUES';

                for ($i = 0; $i < $num_fields; $i++) 
                {
                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result))
                    {
                        $return.="\n(";
                        for($j=0; $j<$num_fields; $j++) 
                        {
                            $row[$j] = addslashes($row[$j]);
                            $row[$j] = preg_replace("#\n#","\\n",$row[$j]);
                            if (isset($row[$j])) { $return.= '"'.$row[$j].'"' ; } else { $return.= '""'; }
                            if ($j<($num_fields-1)) { $return.= ','; }
                        }
                        if (++$i_row == $num_rows) {
                            $return.= ");"; // last row
                        } else {
                            $return.= "),"; // not last row
                        }   
                    }
                }
            }
            $return.="\n\n\n";
        }

        // enable foreign keys
        $return .= 'SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;' . "\r\n";
        $return.= 'COMMIT;';

        //set file path
        if (!is_dir($backup_path)) {
            mkdir($backup_path, 0755, true);
        }

        //delete old file
        //$old_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime('-4 weeks', strtotime($date)));
        //$old_file = $backup_path.$old_date.'-backup'.'.sql';
        //if (file_exists($old_file)) unlink($old_file);

        //save file
        $handle = fopen($backup_path.$date.'-backup'.'.sql','w+');
        fwrite($handle,$return);
        fclose($handle);
    }
}

?>
```

Any recommendations or leads on why it wouldn't actually backup all the tables would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Seeing `addslashes` in here is super not encouraging, that's notoriously flawed. Is there any reason you're not using [`mysqldump`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html) which can do all this and more?

Comment: I know that I can go to myphpadmin and export manually to back up to a single downloadable file, but I wanted this action to reoccur based on a cron schedule. This was a recommendation I found with a few edits. 1st I mainly wanted to catch the content table, but when that didn't work I took out the name of the content table so it would backup the entire database.  Then of course I had to enter my own credentials. I also left $day_of_backup as ' ' instead of designating a day because I plan on doing this nightly at midnight with a cron job.

Comment: What edits would you recommend, in detail please?

Comment: This developer is also sharing the same php script piece which also includes the addslashes - https://davidwalsh.name/backup-mysql-database-php. I don't think I got it from this site, but the script is very much the same. He/she must have been sharing on another forum, possibly this one since i mainly use this one and w3schools.

Comment: That code uses `mysql_query` so it's obsolete and shouldn't be trusted for anything. That entire subsystem was thrown out in PHP 7 because it was so awful. That script is also pointless: `mysqldump` does the job properly, consistently, and is supported by the MySQL team directly.

Comment: Ok, so i need to figure out how I'm going to do this in mysqldump? Thanks for the guidance tadman.

Comment: Do you think this would work?      
<?php
include 'config.php';
include 'opendb.php';
$backupFile = $dbname . date("Y-m-d-H-i-s") . '.zip';
$command = "mysqldump --opt -h $dbhost -u $dbuser -p $dbpass $dbname | zip > $backupFile";
system($command);
include 'closedb.php';
?>         GOT IT FROM: http://www.php-mysql-tutorial.com/wikis/mysql-tutorials/using-php-to-backup-mysql-databases.aspx

Comment: At that point you may as well use a shell script in your cron job. There's no reason to bridge through PHP.

Comment: My plan was to develop this to cover several processes. This script will eventually backup the db to a designated location, name it based on the date of the backup, zip it, then email the zip to me. First things first, getting the backup to take. This is what I have so far:      #!/usr/bin/php
<?php
$file = '/home/user/public_html/path/to/BACKUPS/dly_content_tbl_Backup.sql';
$backupFile = $dbname . date("Y-m-d-H-i-s") . '.zip';
$command = "mysqldump --opt -h localhost -u $user -p $pass $dbname | zip > $backupFile";
system($command);
include 'closedb.php';
?>

Comment: Just write a shell script. PHP will only get in the way here.

Comment: Can all that i mentioned above be done with a shell script? I don't know anything about shell script. Let along writing it from scratch.

Comment: You're already doing a shell script when you call `system`, it's just a tiny one-liner. Expand on that a little to run multiple times if you need to.

Comment: for what ever reason it seems to not be taking my pw. I have my pw, one I know to be correct because it lets me in via ftp and via WHM.  This is the error i'm getting " adding: -Enter password: mysqldump: Got error: 1045: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) when trying to connect
 (stored 0%)
Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 "

Comment: where and what do I enter to call system?

Comment: Figure out what `system` called in your PHP code, exactly, and do that in a shell script. You should get identical results. You can also create a personal `my.cnf` file that [includes the password options](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9293042/how-to-perform-a-mysqldump-without-a-password-prompt) to avoid having to set so many command-line arguments.