# mysqldump prompting password even with credentials saved at /home/user/.my.cnf

Tags: mysql, database, dump

My ultimate goal is to create a `cron` script to automatically dump a selected MySQL database (`ngsRunStats_FK`) once a day. Please note that the MySQL user `ngs_run_stats` has all privileges on MySQL.

I was expecting the answer from Franklin [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9293042/how-to-perform-a-mysqldump-without-a-password-prompt) would do the job, though when I run on the terminal

```
mysqldump --defaults-extra-file=/home/user/.my.cnf  -S /nexus/cliniphenome/mysql.sock -u ngs_run_stats -p ngsRunStats_FK --lock-tables=false > test.sql
```

I am still required to prompt my password. If I enter the password correctly, the dump will work as expected. Though, as stated previously, this should be done automatically i.e. without prompting for the password.

I am assuming that if I am being asked to prompt my password when I call the command on the terminal my `cron` (not shown here) script will not work. Or is this assumption wrong?

My `/home/user/.my.cnf` looks like so:

```
[mysqldump]
user = ngs_run_stats
password = mypassword
```

and has permissions `600`

Comment: can you try without having a space between -p flag and the password? -p[password]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
mysqldump --defaults-extra-file=/home/user/.my.cnf  -S /nexus/cliniphenome/mysql.sock -u ngs_run_stats -pngsRunStats_FK --lock-tables=false > test.sql
```

there should be no space between -p flag and the input password.

However, note that this is an insecure way of connecting to your database as the password will be in plaintext within the command and can be visible through the logs.

Comment: That's why I am trying first to store the credentials at `/home/user/.my.cnf`, which is only accessible by me (`600`)

Comment: I am not sure what is your question then. What does ngsRunStats_FK do?

Comment: that is the database that I am dumping

Answer (score 0):

The mistake is that I am passing the `-p` flag, which will prompt the password. I misread the information from [this website](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-back-up-and-restore-mysql-databases-with-mysqldump/). So I should omit the `-p` flag and the database is actually specified by the `--databases` flag

```
mysqldump --defaults-extra-file=/home/user/.my.cnf  -S /nexus/cliniphenome/mysql.sock -u ngs_run_stats --databases ngsRunStats_FK --lock-tables=false > test4.sql
```