# backup mysql requrie password

Tags: mysql, ssh, cron

I have a script running with cronjob, right now it's not working with cronjob.

If I run script manually via SSH, it requires a password and script working with password.
How can I get past the password requirement and get it to work in cronjob?

This script is on server 1 and MYSQL on server 2, both are on the same local network and use UBUBTU.

backup.sh:
...

```
#!/bin/bash
PRIMARY=10.201.**.**
BACKUPDIR=/home/backuser/backups
FILENAME="daily-sql-$(date +%F-%H.%M).sql.xz"
ssh ${PRIMARY} "sudo mysqldump --single-transaction --quick --no-autocommit -uMysqluser -pMyslpass dbasese | xz" > $BACKUPDIR/$FILENAME
```

...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to perform a mysqldump without a password prompt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9293042/how-to-perform-a-mysqldump-without-a-password-prompt)

Comment: I can not get that solution together with my script.
Maybe not working with ssh?

Comment: SSH should not be the problem. Did you replace your command (mysqldump --single-transaction --quick --no-autocommit -uMysqluser -pMyslpass dbasese | xz) with an example from the link? What was the system's response?

Comment: I tried on two different suggestions but the password request still comes.
I have also tried to create my.cnf with user / pass and it did not work either.

This i use now and dont work without insert password
...
ssh ${PRIMARY} "sudo mysqldump --user='***' --password='***' --single-transaction --quick --no-autocommit --databases db1 db2 | xz" > $BACKUPDIR/$FILENAME

Comment: "I have also tried to create my.cnf with user / pass and it did not work either" - how exactly didn't it work? was there any error message? did you use the parameter --defaults-file as  instructed in the example? did you put the appropriate permissions on .my.cnf? (Pay attention, .my.cnf and not my.cnf !)

Comment: Of course I missed the point before, it has now changed but when I ran the script manually it still asks for password, but it might work in cron without password request.

Comment: Please check and update :)

Comment: same result, dont work with crone or SSH without password promt

Comment: Now I have had more time to look at this.
It is not mysql that wants a password but because I run this via the network as a password is requested.
ssh:
  /var/spool/cron/crontabs/backup-test.sh
Here i need to write password.
How do I get rid of this?