# MySQLDump one INSERT statement for each data row

Tags: mysql

with the following statement:

```
mysqldump --complete-insert --lock-all-tables --no-create-db 
--no-create-info --extended-insert --password=XXX -u XXX 
--dump-date yyy > yyy_dataOnly.sql
```

I get INSERT statements like the following:

```
INSERT INTO `table` VALUES (1,'something'),(2,'anything'),(3,'everything');
```

What I need in my case is something like this:

```
INSERT INTO `table` VALUES (1,'something');
INSERT INTO `table` VALUES (2,'anything');
INSERT INTO `table` VALUES (3,'everything');
```

Is there a way to tell "mysqldump" to create a new INSERT statement for each row?
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 335, accepted):

[Use:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1293575/13627)

```
mysqldump --extended-insert=FALSE
```

Be aware that multiple inserts will be slower than one big insert.

Comment: --skip-extended-insert appears the be the correct syntax for me (using mysqldump version 10.13)

Comment: Slower, yes, but a lot of text editors have trouble with hugely long lines of text and if the tables have a huge amount of data, that is what will happen.

Comment: `mysqldump --opt --skip-extended-insert` or `mysqldump --opt --extended-insert=FALSE` work

Comment: OMG! I migrated to a new version which caused this issue and a lot of my automated scripts to fail. I thought I was screwed but this seems to be like an easy fix. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: I have a question, option "--complete-insert" and "--skip-extended-insert" can be worked together?

Comment: @tquang yes they can, I just tested it.

Comment: This is nice because now I can do a `git diff` on two different database dumps and have a clear picture of what was changed.

Comment: i have a situation where mariadb is not reading its own dump files, and the simple workaround is using your solution.   if i become more motivated, i may try to isolate the problem.

Comment: This makes **git version management of .sql dumps** somehow feasable. When changing just one word in one blogpost then my Wordpress `wp_posts.sql` table dump with `--extended-insert=TRUE` has one line holding ~99.9% of the file contents, which is the diff. With  `--extended-insert=FALSE` the dump has separate insert statements per each line. Then each changed blogpost means only 1 changed row (~0.1% of file). Still 50 paragraphs of that post as one line. But with wrapping + word/character-diff coloring it gets comprehensible. Thx! **W/o that option git scm of SQL dumps is useless.**

Answer (score 22):

In newer versions change was made to the flags:

from the documentation:

> `--extended-insert`, `-e`
>
> Write INSERT statements using multiple-row syntax that includes several VALUES lists. This results in a smaller dump file and speeds up inserts when the file is reloaded.

> `--opt`
>
> This option, enabled by default, is shorthand for the combination of `--add-drop-table` `--add-locks` `--create-options` `--disable-keys` `--extended-insert` `--lock-tables` `--quick` `--set-charset`. It gives a fast dump operation and produces a dump file that can be reloaded into a MySQL server quickly.
>
> Because the `--opt` option is enabled by default, you only specify its converse, the `--skip-opt` to turn off several default settings. See the discussion of mysqldump option groups for information about selectively enabling or disabling a subset of the options affected by `--opt`.

> `--skip-extended-insert`
>
> Turn off extended-insert

Answer (score 3):

For MariaDB you would use

```
mysqldump -u root -p'secret' --skip-extended-insert dbnamehere > y.sql
```

MaraiDB mysqldump [Docs](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mysqldump/)

Comment: Works with MySQL too: [doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_extended-insert)

Answer (score 0):

for people who don't want to `--skip-extended-insert`
// cause (each record has one insert sentence) performance loss when later execute/import sql.

but want keep the sql readability (avoid records in one long line)
this may be work
// didn't find offical solution, just use `sed` to format the sql

NOTE: It's not safe if `),(` in raw data.
TODO: handle `),(` in row data

### use `sed`

```bash
mysqldump ... | sed 's/),(/),\n  (/g'
```

// no newline before first item.

```
mysqldump ... | sed -e 's/),(/),\n  (/g' -e 's/VALUES (/VALUES\n  (/g'
```

// add newline before first item.

### outputs

#### 0. original:

```sql
INSERT INTO `role_permission` VALUES (1328,106,1),(1329,171,1),(1330,144,1),(1331,147,1),(1333,157,1),(1334,88,1);
```

#### 1. become:

```sql
INSERT INTO `role_permission` VALUES (1328,106,1),
  (1329,171,1),
  (1330,144,1),
  (1331,147,1),
  (1333,157,1),
  (1334,88,1);
```

```sql
INSERT INTO `role_permission` VALUES
  (1328,106,1),
  (1329,171,1),
  (1330,144,1),
  (1331,147,1),
  (1333,157,1),
  (1334,88,1);
```

http://blog.lavoie.sl/2014/06/split-mysqldump-extended-inserts.html

https://stackoverflow.com/q/15750535#answer-19961480
Solution came from here, I didn't do fully test

Comment: The problem with this is that it will break for strings that happen to contain `),(`

Comment: Useful for diff'ing SQL dumps, but not good for dumps where you need to trust the data.  (If you are just diffing, you might as well just remove each `),(` and replace with a single linebreak.

Comment: yes, you were right, it's not safe for `),(`, I wonder is there a easy way to escape or protect it

Comment: This does not solve _anything_, as far as "performance loss" is involved.

Comment: @Luuk this solution avoid split into one value each insert (which generate too many inset sentence that slow down when later execute  import them) by use multi-lines values split by sed. but  not process special string safely

Comment: @Luuk the point is keep sql readability (be close to --skip-extended-insert dose), but avoid generate too many insert sentence for each row value (not safe workaround by sed)