# Limit rows per insert in mysqldump

Tags: import, insert, export, mysql

I'm piping `mysqldump` output trough `perl -pane 's{(VALUES |\),)\(}{$1\n  (}smg'`, so each insert row is on new line, like so:

```
INSERT INTO (col1, col2, ...) VALUES
  (value1, value2, ...),
  (value1, value2, ...),
  ...
```

But when i try to import this file, then those newlines and spaces produce `MySQL has gone away` error, because packet is too large.

**Can i tell `mysqldump` how many rows(or bytes) to dump per insert?**

Comment: can you change mysql server options to set a larget packet size or longer timeouts, or this has to be accomplished by modifying the dump?

Comment: No, i cant change them. I could live without that formatting, but i just hoped that it could be accomplished.

Answer (score 1):

You might like this one, it adds insert into for each row:

mysqldump --extended-insert=FALSE

Source:
[MySQLDump one INSERT statement for each data row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12439353/mysqldump-one-insert-statement-for-each-data-row)

Answer (score -3):

Use the where option:

```
mysqldump --opt --where="1 limit 100" myDb
```

Comment: That limits the whole dump, not per insert