# phpmyadmin show error code 500 when import database

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

[image]

I already adjust php.ini but still not working , please help.

http://edumediator.com/info.php

Comment: Hello! Did any of our solutions helped?

Answer (score 0):

Run this query first

```
select @@sql_mode
```

go to the mysql my.cnf file and add this at the end of file:

```
sql_mode = "STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
```

Restart MySQL

If it didn't help, try to Export and Import your database with Compatibiliy Mode as None.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, it was often cause by these two possible reasons: 1. Permissions of phpmyadmin's files, and 2. The SQL query is too large.

#### 1. Resetting the Permission of phpmyadmin

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/josephgodwinkimani/cyberpanel-mods/), you can run the following script to fix the permissions.

```
sh <(curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tbaldur/cyberpanel-mods/main/fix_permissions.sh || wget -O - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tbaldur/cyberpanel-mods/main/fix_permissions.sh)
```

#### 2. SQL query is too large

Accoding to [Limit rows per insert in mysqldump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16010267/limit-rows-per-insert-in-mysqldump) and [Lost connection to MySQL server during query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6516943/lost-connection-to-mysql-server-during-query), mysqldump often creates a query that may be too large to process for some MySQL servers. You have the following options

a. Increase the maximum allowable packets in my.ini:

```
max_allowed_packet=32M
```

b. Manually import through shell.

```
mysql -u <user> --password=<password> <database name> < file_to_import.sql
```

c. Limit the Insert Value query when running mysqldump before importing.

```
mysqldump --extended-insert=FALSE <next params...>
```