# mysqldump and separating INSERT's

Tags: mysql

When I run the following mysqldump command, it groups the INSERT's together.

```
mysqldump --user=username --password=password --host=localhost database | gzip > /parth/to/folder/backup.sql.gz
```

E.g:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_name VALUES (1,2,3), (4,5,6), (7,8,9)
```

This is great for space saving but makes it difficult for me to import a 3GB sql file. I have a script that uploads a large SQL file in parts. It breaks up the lines so that the server/page doesn't time out.

What I'd prefer is this:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_name VALUES (1,2,3);
INSERT INTO tbl_name VALUES (4,5,6);
INSERT INTO tbl_name VALUES (7,8,9);
```

Is that possible?

Comment: Why does it make difficult? A single `INSERT` statement is better than many separate ones!

Comment: You mean something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12439353/mysqldump-one-insert-statement-for-each-data-row

Comment: You could also split the zip file, upload it, unpack it on the server and import it via socket => not timeout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it via:

```
mysqldump -uUSER --skip-extended-insert -p DATABASE | gzip > dump.sql.gz
```

where `USER` is your user, `DATABASE` is your database.

But - really, why do that? Multiple insert is better in terms of performance.

Also, hint: if you're typing this command (i.e. it's not a part of some script) - do not provide password since it will be saved in history (by default) - that may be unsecure (in sample above single-standing `-p` option indicates interactive password prompt)

Comment: That's what I wanted. Let's just say I'm a bit of a noob and am using this script to import my database without timing out http://www.ozerov.de/bigdump/. At the moment I don't know all the fancy side of splitting sql files, uploading with sockets etc. This is just a quick way for me to get what I need done until I can learn more about big databases :) Appreciate your help!