# Random syntax error on mysql import for mariadb 10.1 from mysqldump mysql 5.6

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a mysqldump from a server running 
`mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.35, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper` centos 6
I am trying to import it to a server that is running mariadb `mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.22-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1`
That is running Centos7

I am constantly getting a syntax error like this `ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 4908: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '),('5051888098585',2512,131872,359,'Pending','completed','0','1','2016-03-15 17' at line 1`

The line number appears random, if i drop the tables and start the restore again it can fail again at a point before that line or after. Sometimes it almost makes it to the end. The one think that is constant is that the line is always a big insert query.

Similar questions here do not solve my problem.
I have completely rebuild the server ,changed multiple mysqldump settings and my.cnf settings, nothing changes.

Current my.cnf

```
    [mysqld]
bind-address = ::
skip_name_resolve
local-infile=0
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0
# Settings user and group are ignored when systemd is used.
# If you need to run mysqld under a different user or group,
# customize your systemd unit file for mariadb according to the
# instructions in http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Systemd



max_allowed_packet =  1G
max_connections = 600
thread_cache_size = 16
query_cache_size = 64M
tmp_table_size= 512M
max_heap_table_size= 512M
wait_timeout=60

#Innodb Settings
innodb_file_per_table=1
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 25G
innodb_log_file_size = 2048M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 0
innodb_file_format = Barracuda
innodb_flush_neighbors = 0

#Log

log-error =/var/log/error.log
tmpdir = /dev/shm
```

I have tried dozens of different settings for the import and for the dump nothing worked.These are the latest:
For the dump

```
mysqldump -u admin -p`cat /etc/psa/.psa.shadow` --master-data=2 db_name --default-character-set=utf8 -c -Q  --result-file=dump.sql
```

For the import

```
mysql -uadmin -p`cat /etc/psa/.psa.shadow` db_name < dump.sql
```

Comment: How much RAM?..

Comment: @RickJames 32G.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't override it, `mysqldump` generates vast `INSERT` statements that handle lots of rows at a time. It seems likely something's going wrong on your restore because of the length of the `INSERT` lines.

Try using [the `--net_buffer_length=8192` option](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_net_buffer_length) on `mysqldump` when you create your dump file. It will generate shorter `INSERT` statements. Your dump file will be longer and will take longer to restore, but it may actually run to completion.

If that doesn't work, and you have time, try [the `--skip-opt` option](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_skip-opt) to skip all optimization.

See this: [How to deal with enormous line lengths created by mysqldump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293529/how-to-deal-with-enormous-line-lengths-created-by-mysqldump)

Comment: Thank you. i used --net_buffer_length=8192 to export the dump and it imported with no issues.